How use KeyCloak to assign access to once record of application database table based on postgres?
I have two DB.

KeyCloak  DB which stores users, realm, roles and other info of AuthServer.
Application DB which swores data of my application (for example, list of notes, posts and so on).

My question is how can I assign access to specific records of these tables for specific KeyCloak users.
I'v learned many examples on various stacks, but many of them do not even use the application database.
But I understand one thing. We can assign privileges and permissions for specific resourse. So in my case resourses are REST API endpoints.
Is it possible to solve this problem in simple ways, without resorting to using providers?
Thanks:)

If I understand correctly, you want:

Authenticate a user on KC to access some REST endpoints
Limit what this user can retrieve on PG database

You can't do this:

PG don't have ways to limit grants to records (rows)
KC users are not PG users

Solution:
The correct behavior is to make all permissions on application level, and KC can help passing roles to your application make the decisions of what that user can access.
